# Having trouble installing cowpatty

Tags: networking

Does anyone know where to get the newest version of cowpatty? I've typed the following:

```
wget http://wirelessdefence.org/Contents/Files/cowpatty-4.6.tgz
```

but it comes back with 'error 404 file not found'.

Answer (score 1):

Get it from [the project page](http://www.willhackforsushi.com/?page_id=50) or directly with `wget`:

```
wget www.willhackforsushi.com/code/cowpatty/4.6/cowpatty-4.6.tgz
```

Comment: that worked!! now I'm looking for the fixup16 patch. any suggestions?